# Axios patch request doesn't work with window.location.reload() in Django-React app

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios

I have a frontend React and backend Django Rest Framework app. I try to make a patch request with Axios and it works fine. But then, wueh I try to reload the page with window.location.reload(), the patch request works sometimes, I can't figure out why this happens.

I want to reload the Card components, I've tried to pass a State to the component but it doesn't re-render.
My code:

```
function App() {

  const [temas, setTemas] = useState([]);


  const añadirTema = (nuevoTema) => {
    setTemas(prev => [...prev, nuevoTema]);
  };

  const quitarTema = (id) => {
    setTemas(current => 
      current.filter((item) => item.id !== id));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchTemas = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/temas_activos/',
      );
      setTemas(result.data);
    };
    fetchTemas();
  }, []);

  const validarComentarios = (event) => {


    const fetchComentarioPorValidar = async (tema) => {
      const result = await axios(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comentario_por_validar/?id_tema=${tema.id}`,
      );
      console.log(tema, result.data);

     if (result.data.length === 1 ) {
      const resultValidacion = await axios.patch(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comentarios/${result.data[0].id}/`,
        {estado: true},
      ).catch(err => console.log(err.response.data));
      
     };
    };

    temas.forEach(tema => {
      fetchComentarioPorValidar(tema);
    }); 

    window.location.reload(); //When add this line patch request works sometimes
    

  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale="es-mx">
      <div className='pt-3 mx-auto w-5/6'>
        <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold inline">
          Temas
        </h1>
        <button onClick={validarComentarios} className='float-right'>Validar</button>
      </div>
      
      {temas.map(item => (
        <Card 
          key={item.id}
          id={item.id}
          titulo={item.titulo}
          fecha={item.fecha_creacion}
          quitarTema={quitarTema}
        />))
      }
      <NuevoTemaForm 
        actualizar={añadirTema}
      />

    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```